# search date ranges on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the products that do not have the date range that I pass (it will be a parameter). I was able to write this query, but it is limited because it does not consider a reservation with a previous "check in" or a later "check out".

Can you help me?

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings b
  right join products p ON b.product_id = p.id
WHERE b.check_in_date >= '2022-11-10' AND NOT b.check_out_date <= '2022-11-25';
```

The output would be all products that do not have any booking with dates within the range.

[image]

Comment: So, presumably, you want any check in before the check out date, and any check out after the check in date. I'm not entirely clear on what you're seeking, and unless you are, you wont find it easy to write the query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because I can't comment, but how about:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings b
  right join products p ON b.product_id = p.id
WHERE NOT (b.check_in_date >= '2022-11-10' AND b.check_out_date <= '2022-11-25');
```

Thus getting all the bookings which are not within the bounds ?

Note, this is equivalent to:

```
...WHERE b.check_in_date < '2022-11-10' OR b.check_out_date > '2022-11-25'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting data from bookings, but you say you want products.
So, I would go like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
JOIN bookings b ON b.product_id = p.id
WHERE b.productId NOT IN 
(SELECT bo.productId FROM bookings bo 
WHERE bo.check_in_date >= '2022-11-10'
AND b.check_out_date <='2022-11-25');
```

Didn't test it, but at least should give you an idea how to think about it.